# Disable payment methods based on WooCommerce cart total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-method, array-unset

I tried this code below to hide/disable Credit/Debit card and Direct bank transfer payment method on Woo commerce(WordPress) when the checkout total == 400  but did not work. Please any idea on how to achieve this? Thank you so kindly.

```
function payment_gateway_disable_total_amount( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['bacs'] ) && $woocommerce->cart->total == 400 ) {
        unset(  $available_gateways['bacs'] );
    }
    
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['youpay'] ) && $woocommerce->cart->total == 400 ) {
        unset(  $available_gateways['youpay'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_total_amount' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why using a fixed total? There is very few chances that any customer get speifically 400 as total. It should be "up to 400" instead, so something like `if( $tolal >= 400 )`.

Also "Debit/Credit Cards" doesn't seem to be the right Payment method Id… See [this thread][1] to find out the right Payment method Id for "Debit/Credit Cards" payment gateway.

Try the following *(assuming that "Debit/Credit Cards" payment method id is correct)*:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'show_hide_payment_methods' );
function show_hide_payment_methods( $available_gateways ) {

    if ( WC()->cart->total >= 400 ) {
        if ( isset($available_gateways['bacs']) ) {
            unset($available_gateways['bacs']);
        }
        if ( isset($available_gateways['Debit/Credit Cards']) ) {
            unset($available_gateways['Debit/Credit Cards']);
        }
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you so kindly it worked. I was able to get the payment method id too. Thanks